# Mac OSX PHP and XAMPP path issue

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on Mac OSX running Yosemite
I have created the .bash_profile file like this:

```
export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin/php:${PATH}
export PATH
```

When I type echo $PATH in terminal, I get correct XAMPP path
But when I type "which php" it shows /usr/bin/php

How can I make my XAMPP use the correct php instead of default php that came with mac?

Comment: I think your XAMPP_HOME path is wrong, try removing `/xamppfiles`

Answer (score 104):

To use the XAMPP PHP and other binaries found in `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/` add the following to the appropriate `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file depending on your default shell (see note below).

```bash
export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP
export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

Reload the current login shell to apply the changes (won't be needed next time you open a shell session):

```bash
$ exec $SHELL -l;
```

Confirm:

```bash
$ which php
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php
```

**Note: zsh vs bash**

Since [MacOS Catalina (v10.15, released 2019), the default shell is zsh rather than bash](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050). To find your current shell, open Terminal and type:

```bash
$ echo $SHELL
```

The output will most likely be either `/bin/zsh` or `/bin/bash` unless you changed to another shell at some time.

Follow the instructions above and if using zsh then add the required lines to `~/.zshrc` and if using bash then add them to `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem...!! earlier i was not loading bash_profile using 'source ~/.bash_profile'

Comment: What's the correct path to XAMPP's php in the latest version (7)? It is quite different

Comment: launching next terminal, which php return old path

Comment: Do you found any solution for this issue that lunching next terminal return old path?? @rfan-ul-haq

Comment: I have installed xampp 8.0 in macbook. It was installed at "/Users/kamlesh/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/". It is working in the browser. xampp 8.0 has php 8 and I want to set its path in bash_profile file so that when i use php -v command in terminal then it should show php 8.0 version. I have set strings in bash_profile as, but not working yet, any suggestion: export XAMPP_HOME=/Users/kamlesh/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root
export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH

Answer (score 17):

In My case I did the following

I created my bash profile.

`sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`

And then added the following to it

```
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

And then refreshed my path
`source ~/.bash_profile`
Or if that doesn't work you can close the terminal completely and start a new session.

Enter `which php`
And you would see your new php path, in my case `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin`
If you know what php version you installed, you can also check by entering `php -v` in my case it output the following.

`PHP 5.6.14 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2015 20:37:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies.`

Comment: any suggestion for xampp 8.0 in mac? Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Finally I Solve the Problem. I set the Following Config in my "~/.bash_profile"

If u have a bash_profile U need to Edit otherWise create bash_profile. Then Add these lines 1st

```
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Above is the Xampp path. Next Add The Composer Path(IF U ADD THE COMPOSER PATH 1st IT WON'T WORK)

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Finally Working Fine for Me.

```
which php
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php
```

Comment: I have installed xampp 8.0 version in mac but there no Xampp directory in Applications directory. Kindly suggest how can we set php path for Xampp 8.0 version in Mac. Thanks a lot.

Comment: it works but after restart again shows older version

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve the problem.
On the Mac, the XAMPP bin folder and the php file had the wrong permission, hence it was not working.
Secondly, I also had to profile the full path

```
/bin/php-5.5.15:${PATH}
```

Thanks

Comment: If this solved your problem and you are happy with the answer, please accept this answer (so it does not appear in the unanswered questions list)

Answer (score -1):

1.Open terminal

2.Run:

```
echo "$SHELL"
```

3.if result is "/bin/zsh", Run:

```
sudo nano ~/.zshrc
```

else Run:

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and enter your devices password

4.add theese lines to the end of the file:

```
export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin/php:${PATH}
export PATH
```

5.then control+X and enter twice

6.restart

Comment: Please explain the value that your advice adds to this page.  As a reader who is not an expert in this subject matter, it would help me to decide if I should use your advice if you explain how it differs from earlier answers.