# Setting $PATH in xampp osx

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp

Good morning all,
I have a little problem with variable $PATH in my .bash_profile file.

I have an OSX system with XAMPP installed.
I have edit my .bash_profile in this way:

```
export XAMPP_HOME="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles"
export PATH="${XAMPP_HOME}/bin/php-5.4.22:${PATH}"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/alessandrominoccheri/Sites/site.com/lib/Cake/Console"
export PATH
```

After I have restart apache and write into console:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and type:

```
which php
```

But always return me:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

How can I change path?
I have changed permission on bin folder but same problem.
I have  followed this link but I have the same problem:

[Mac OSX PHP and XAMPP path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011941/mac-osx-php-and-xampp-path-issue)

Comment: Is `${XAMPP_HOME}/bin/php-5.4.22` *the* executable or a directory?

Comment: is an executable @deceze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `${XAMPP_HOME}/bin/php-5.4.22` is the executable, then adding it to your path doesn't help you in being able to call it using `php`. The `$PATH` needs to contain *directories* in which executables are, which will be searched in the order they're defined whenever you mention any executable by name.

You either want to `alias` your `php-5.4.22` to `php` in your profile, or maybe better, create a symlink for it that overrides your default `php`. E.g.:

```
$ ln -s ${XAMPP_HOME}/bin/php-5.4.22 /usr/local/bin/php
```

Comment: Ok I have done it! Thanks, but how can i know if it takes the right php if I have make a symlink?

Comment: `which php`, `ls -l $(which php)`

Comment: Thanks. This very helpful

Comment: What if `ln: /usr/bin/php: File exists`?