# Why is php 5.3 while my xampp is php 7?

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I was installed XAMPP with php version 5.3.
Now i install newer XAMPP with php 7.1
I check php version on localhost is 7.1 but when i check it on terminal with command `php -v` then it show php 5.3.
So, How can i disable php version 5.3 and use only 7.1?

I use OSX 10. Thank you!

Comment: Check this out [XAMPP with Multiple PHP Versions](http://superuser.com/questions/123902/getting-xampp-to-work-with-multiple-version-of-php)

Comment: Mac OSX runs a core installed version of php. You have to point the core version to the new version for it to show the correct version. It is not recommended doing this because it may "break" some OS X features. That being said, I have done this and it's been fine. Your php version is in the `/etc` invisible folder.

Comment: I should also mention that if your php is running the 7.x under `XAMPP` then the terminal version doesn't matter.

Comment: How to point it @Rasclatt ?

Comment: Is your XAMPP using the `7.1`? On your web page just do `phpinfo();` If it says `7.1` then it's no big deal that the system still uses `5.3`

Comment: Yes, my XAMPP is using 7.x, but i need my OSX using 7.x too, because of i    use phpunit end it require php 5.6+ :(

Comment: Thank you so much, I resolved it. Add try to add new php version into $PATH and it work.

Comment: @PhongVân: can you please update the $PATH in comment or update your solution as answer to this question?

Comment: @PhongVân: Next minute, I found this answer and it saves my lot of work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011941/mac-osx-php-and-xampp-path-issue

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XAMPP as a server then the other version of PHP doesn't matter. XAMPP will use the version it installed