# artisan clear-compiled return error code 255

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

When runnning `composer install` on my laravel project I get the error:

> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255

Any advice on what could be the issue? Note composer installs all the vendor packages. The full output is below:

> [user@some_path]$ composer update
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update
>   Generating autoload files
>   > php artisan clear-compiled
>   Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

Comment: From all the random "correct" answers, I can deduct that this comes from an error in code, but it may be anywhere in the project.  For me, it was on the Exception Handler.  I extended a class that was not available.

Good luck finding out the source for real problem.

Answer (score 13):

Makse sure your `storage/ & bootstrap/cache` directory writeable.

Make sure your .env file doesent contain any spaces.

Ex: 
`key=value istead of key=va lue`

remove the
`bootstrap/cache/config.php` file.
then

```
composer dumpautoload
composer update
```

Try to remove `/bootstrap/compiled.php` ( if you have it )

Comment: And make sure you HAVE a .env file, in my n00b case.

Comment: Also make sure your autoloaded directories like `src` in many cases do not contain fatal errors for parsing.

Answer (score 2):

step 1 - Check your php version. If your laravel is old , then it wont support 7.x, you need to switch ([check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011941/mac-osx-php-and-xampp-path-issue) this if you are using mac) to PHP 5.6 in this case.

Step 2 - remove composer.lock and run `composer install`

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that command does is delete the `bootstrap/cache/services.php` file, if it exists. Most likely, the file exists, but the permissions aren't set correctly to allow you to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. Here is list of extensions that causes this problem.

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

you have to uncomment all of these extensions from your php.ini

> E:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.ini

**Note :: Must check your database credential into your `.env` file**

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem can come from multiple sources. In my case, I had a syntax error in my config/app.php. Reverted to a previous version and the remade my edits.

Answer (score -1):

Just run the `npm install` command from any terminal then re-run composer to install all your dependencies.