# How to fix 'package:discover' error in laravel?

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.7

I want to run artisan command and i can't because of the problem.

I try to search answer in the internet but there is no solution for my error. There are solutions for other type of errors, but there is no information for this one.

php artisan ... -> gives no result
all of this composer commands throw an exception:
composer install,
composer update,
composer dump-autoload
...

> Generating optimized autoload files
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
>
> Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

Comment: Did you try the responses of this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570359/artisan-clear-compiled-return-error-code-255 ?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see that problem differs from my.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

My solution (Laravel 6) was to run the following commands from the root of the application:

```
mkdir -p storage/framework
mkdir -p storage/framework/sessions
mkdir -p storage/framework/views
mkdir -p storage/framework/cache
```

And then rerun

```
php artisan package:discover --ansi
```