# Why is Xdebug not working with XAMPP, even though it says it is installed in Terminal?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, xdebug

I am required to use XAMPP for my university class, but I cannot get Xdebug to work with it.

I am using an M2 MacBook Air. I followed all the steps as listed by the Xdebug wizard, but no luck.

Both php.ini files in the XAMPP directory and `opt/homebrew` directory have these lines added:

```ini
zend_extension=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug,develop
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.client_host=172.17.0.1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.max_nesting_level=250
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=10
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

The `xdebug.so` file is in that directory, I have checked.

When I enter `php --version` into Terminal, it shows that Xdebug is installed:

```text
PHP 8.2.10 (cli) (built: Aug 31 2023 18:52:55) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2023, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.10, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

But, when I go to the XAMPP `phpinfo.php` page and copy-paste my data into the Xdebug wizard, it keeps telling me that Xdebug is not installed. Please help me in this!

The Xdebug wizard output:

```text
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 8.2.4
Zend API nr: 420220829
PHP API nr: 20220829
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
OPcache Loaded: no
Configuration File Path: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
Configuration File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
Extensions directory: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829
```

Comment: You need to confirm that you have edited the php.ini displayed in phpinfo.

Comment: `/var/log/` is not writable.  Try `/usr/local/var/log` to place the xdebug.log file. After you do, restart apache, and the php-fpm process.

Comment: are you absolutely certain about the IP address ?  try localhost no ?  127.0.0.1.

Comment: finally, the xampp version is 8.2.4 ... and you are testing at cli with another version (possibly brewed).   Did you try to run `php --version` with the one in the xampp distribution.  Quite possibly, they did not build into it the xdebug extension.

Comment: If you're running PHP as Apache module you need the thread-safe version of the PHP interpreter and, I'd guess, matching extensions. But you're trying to load `non-zts` Xdebug. If you only need the Xampp setup, I'd get rid of the other, it'll just confuse you.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález i could argue get rid of xampp :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@YvesLeBorg can't really get rid of XAMPP because my uni professor requires us to use it...
Anyways, thank you very much for the insight on the different PHP versions.

I uninstalled and deleted the PHP being detected by the CLI as to not confuse them, and then added these lines to my `~/.zshrc` file by using `sudo nano ~/.zshrc`:

```
export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP
export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```

...and then reloaded the login shell with:

```
$ exec $SHELL -l;
```

...which recognized the XAMPP PHP installation as the default.
Huge thanks to this thread: [Mac OSX PHP and XAMPP path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011941/mac-osx-php-and-xampp-path-issue)

After that, when I used `php -v`, it showed me this:

```
Failed loading /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so, 0x0009): tried: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so' (no such file), '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
PHP 8.2.4 (cli) (built: Apr  6 2023 04:12:41) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

...which shows that the PHP, and therefore the xdebug.so file from homebrew and XAMPP were compiled for different architectures. So, I downloaded the x86_64 build of xdebug using:

```
arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Finally, I set the path to the new xdebug.so in the php.ini as:

```
zend_extension=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/xdebug.so
```

after which Xdebug is finally working! :)